# QR scanning, result - "com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode@ecd6456"

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I have problem, dont know what to do, Goal is to make QR scanner, you enter value then press OK it should store the values in object podaci and to use same values in other activitiy.

But what happens it scans QR code but it doesnt show real value it shows something like this : "com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode@ecd6456" and  there is no value stored in object podaci in MainActivity.

here is my QR class :

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.irhad.mytestapplication.data.Podaci;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class QRActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    SurfaceView camera_preview;
    Intent main;
    EditText txtUnosUplacenog;
    TextView txtQRIspis;
    Button btnOK;
    private Podaci podaci;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qr_activity);

        camera_preview = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        txtUnosUplacenog = findViewById(R.id.txtUnosUplacenog);
        btnOK = findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        txtQRIspis = findViewById(R.id.txtQRIspis);
        podaci = new Podaci();
        createCameraSource();
    }


    private void createCameraSource() {
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).build();
        final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(620, 480)
                .build();

        camera_preview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(QRActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(camera_preview.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });//camera_preview

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {}

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes  = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if(barcodes.size() > 0){

                    podaci.setQrvalue(barcodes.valueAt(0).toString());
                    podaci.setUplata(Double.parseDouble(txtUnosUplacenog.getText().toString()));
                    txtQRIspis.setText(podaci.getQrvalue());
                }
            }
        });//barcodeDetector

    }//CreateCameraSource

    public void btnOK(View view){
        if(podaci.getUplata() != 0 && podaci.getQrvalue() != "")
            izadji(podaci);
    }

    public void izadji(Podaci podatak){
        main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        main.putExtra("barcode", podatak.getQrvalue() );
        main.putExtra("vrijednost", podatak.getUplata() );
        startActivity(main);
        finish();
    }

    public void izadji(View view){
        main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And here is my MainActivity class :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.irhad.mytestapplication.data.Podaci;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSkenirajQR;
    Button btnOpcije;
    Button btnExit;
    TextView txtIspis;
    boolean baterija_ispisano = false;

    BroadcastReceiver batteryInfo = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            if(level <= 10 && !baterija_ispisano){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Molim vas napunite bateriju (<10%)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        baterija_ispisano = true;
            }else if(level >= 11 && baterija_ispisano){
                baterija_ispisano = false;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSkenirajQR = findViewById(R.id.btnSkener);
        btnOpcije = findViewById(R.id.btnOpcije);
        btnExit = findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        txtIspis = findViewById(R.id.txtIspis);

    }

    public void open_Skener(View view){
        Intent qrskeniranje = new Intent(this, QRActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(qrskeniranje,0);
        finish();
    }

    public void open_Opcije(View view){
        Intent opcije = new Intent(this, OpcijeActivity.class);
        startActivity(opcije);
        finish();
    }

    public void izadji(View view){
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if(data != null){
             String qr = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
             String value = data.getParcelableExtra("vrijednost");
             txtIspis.setText("Barcode vrijednost : " + qr);
         } else {
             txtIspis.setText("Nije ocitalo");
         }
    }
}
```

Ps :And it is changing value while im holding in front of QR code. 
@gr54943, @ac45c04 etc...

Comment: looks like something wrong in your onActivityResult code. you are setting parcelable value to a string.. I think it should be some barcode/Qrcode object which will give you the read value..

Comment: @pop thanks, but still one question remains, why i dont have any values in MainActivity object podaci

Comment: which object you mean.

Comment: podaci.setQrvalue(barcodes.valueAt(0).toString()); remove .tostring while putting in intent

Comment: onActivityResult retrieve value like this 
 Barcode barcode =  data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");